# Mysql file upload error?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code to upload a file. Everything is working perfect. This code uploads the file to destination folder and MySQL query work perfect and insert all data into their relative fields in database. But it is not going to the page which is mentioned in header() function. It  gives me an error at the end like this

> Error: please try again, 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

I think it occurs when last if($exe) is executed

```
<?php

include('./includes/connection.php');

if(!$_POST['song_name']){
    header('location: pro_add.php');
    exit;
}

$path = "../upload_data/";
$uniqid = uniqid(strtotime('now'));
$uniq_name = $uniqid .'_'. $_FILES['file']['name'];

$complete_path = $path . $uniq_name;

$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$complete_path);

if(!$move){
    echo 'Error: please try again'."<br/>";
}

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products SET
    sub_cat_id='".$_POST['sub_cat_id']."',
    song_name='".$_POST['song_name']."',
    artist='".$_POST['artist']."',
    path='".$complete_path."' ");

$exe = mysql_query($query);

if($exe){
    header('location: products.php');
    exit;
}else{
    echo 'Error: please try again, <br />' . mysql_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you doing a mysql_query() on mysql_query()'s output. That's probably your problem. Also, start escaping your variables before putting them anywhere near the DB.

Comment: You also may want to read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and also mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the result of your query:

```
$query = mysql_query('...');
$exe   = mysql_query($query);
```

Just replace `$query = mysql_query('...');` with `$exe = mysql_query('...')` and it should work.

**EDIT**

As commenters on your question also pointed out, your script is *extremely* vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should read up on that before putting this online.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1):

code is fine but it has only one problem. may be it has gone out of your mind...

```
 $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products SET
           sub_cat_id='".$_POST['sub_cat_id']."',
           song_name='".$_POST['song_name']."',
           artist='".$_POST['artist']."',
           path='".$complete_path."' ");
```

instead of this you should write

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products SET
          sub_cat_id='".$_POST['sub_cat_id']."',
          song_name='".$_POST['song_name']."',
          artist='".$_POST['artist']."',
          path='".$complete_path."'";
```

it will work fine if you replace this much of code..